# Given that there is generally no 'right' or 'wrong' answer in UX design, does it mean that people are less likely to award a tick to answers at UXSE?

Tags: discussion

I recently just answered a couple of questions over at a number of different Stack Exchange sites, and within a very short amount of time I received upvotes on the answers and also had those answers accepted by the OP.

I know that UX design questions tend to be contextual, but I wonder if the prevailing view that there can be many different valid solutions and that we need to consider and validate solutions with users, but does it also lead to people on UXSE less inclined to accept answers?

What are you experiences on UXSE and other Stack Exchange site?